# What is the problem using string manipulation functions with MySql?

Tags: c++, mysql, windows, 64-bit

I have a MySQL 8.0.17 database sample project I am compiling using Visual Studio CE 2017 on a 64 bit windows machine. It is a console app. See the code below it's boilerplate. The issue I have is when trying to manipulate strings after initializing the database. ie: uncommenting the sprintf_s() causes an exception to be thrown. I am trying to understand if this is somehow by design or is it a bug? Or is there something else I may be doing wrong?

```
include "pch.h"
include <windows.h> 
include <iostream> 
include <winsock.h> 
include <stdio.h> 
include <mysql.h>

int main()
{   std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    MYSQL conn;
    MYSQL_RES *res_set;
    MYSQL_ROW row;

    mysql_init(&conn);

    char str[6];
 // sprintf_s(str, 5, "test");

    if(!mysql_real_connect(&conn,"localhost","usr","pas","db",0,NULL,0))
    {   fprintf(stderr, "Connection Failed: %s\n", mysql_error(&conn));
    } else
    {   fprintf(stderr, "Successfully connected to Database.\n");
        int status = mysql_query(&conn, "SELECT * FROM users");
        res_set = mysql_store_result(&conn);
        int count = mysql_num_rows(res_set);
        printf("No of rows = %d\n", count);
        while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res_set)) != NULL)
        {   for (int i = 0; i < mysql_num_fields(res_set); i++)
            {   printf("%s \t", row != NULL ? row : "NULL");
            } printf("\n");
        }
    }
    mysql_close(&conn);
 // getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I find it interesting that if I place the sprintf_s() above
the mysql_init() it works just fine? So does that mean I need to open a new connection on each request? Because it did not work this way in version 5.7 where I could establish a connection then execute several statements. Any response would be greatly appreciated as I've been struggling with this for a while now...

The following is the Exception being thrown by the debugger at the call to mysql_num_rows() when the sprintf_s() is included in the compilation...

Exception thrown at 0x00007FFED78550C0 (libmysql.dll) in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.

So, I stripped it down to as few lines as possible to reproduce the error:

```
int main()
{   MYSQL conn;
    MYSQL_RES *res_set;

    mysql_init(&conn);

    char str[50];
    strcpy_s(str, "test");

    if (mysql_real_connect(&conn,"localhost","user","pass","db",0,NULL,0))
    {   int status = mysql_query(&conn, "SELECT * FROM users");
        res_set = mysql_store_result(&conn);
        int count = mysql_num_rows(res_set);  // Exception is thrown here.
    }
    mysql_close(&conn);
}
```

Now why does this happen?  Thanks, Brian..

Comment: That line should not be causing an exception. More likely, there is undefined behavior elsewhere and adding this line causes the compiler to emit different code that causes the UB to manifest differently.

Comment: For example, possible UB: `printf("%s \t", row != NULL ? row : "NULL");`.  `MYSQL_ROW` is not a type compatible with the `%s` code so this is likely where the program is stopping. Use a debugger -- which line of code does the debugger halt on due to the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Your are not checking if any of the rows fields are NULL

Use instead

```
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res_set)) != NULL)
{ for (int i = 0; i < mysql_num_fields(res_set); i++)
  {
    printf("%s ", row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL");  
  } 
  printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to those who answered my question. I rolled back to version 5.7 of MySQL and it is working correctly. Perhaps I tried to adopt the newer cutting edge version 8.0 a little too early.?